# want to combine multiple array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i want to do this type

in my form i have check box array and the function i want to call as the size of check box array,
now all is ok simple one time calling.

but i want to call the function as above,
and store the function return value in one array

as function return array so i want to do like 
this

for user id 1->callfunction return array
user id 2->callfunction return array
....
....

i have try to used the array_push but i does not get any result

here is my code

```
$track = array();

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($usr);$i++)
        {
            if (!empty($start) and !empty($end))
            {

                $track_e = $tracker->getProjectTrack($id, $usr[$i], $taski, $start, $end);

                //$track = $tracker->getProjectTrack($id, $usr, $taski, $start, $end);
            }

            $track=array_push($track,$track_e);

        }
```

Comment: Please clearify the question. What does the input array look like? What does `$tracker->getProjectTack()` do? And what you do expect `$track` to look like after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5  ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) )

instead of this it returns

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 9) ) )

something like that

so i want to return it in as same first one.

Comment: Please do not supply additional information to your question as an answer. SO does not work like a forum. Please use the [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3123038/edit) link below your question

Comment: How come you want to have an array with [0] elements that simply point to a one element array? Wouldn't the first one make a little bit more sense? Please clarify how exactly you want these arrays to be structured with some more examples and more importantly, WHY it needs to be like that.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to go through array, use foreach

```
$track = array();
if (!empty($start) and !empty($end)){  
 foreach ($usr as $u){
  array_push($track,$tracker->getProjectTrack($id, $u, $taski, $start, $end);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanx it works but it not added element in desire way like this

Answer (score 1):

***Solution:***

```
$track=array_push($track,$track_e);
```

[`array_push`](http://www.php.net/array_push) doesn't return an array; it returns the new number of elements in the array, modifying the array it receives as an argument in-place. It's actually much easier to just write:

```
$track []= $track_e;
```

***Suggestion:***

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($usr);$i++) {
    # ...
    $track_e = $tracker->getProjectTrack($id, $usr[$i], $taski, $start, $end);
```

Why not simplify the process of indexing `$usr` and counting the number of elements in it like so:

```
foreach ($usr as $usr_elem) {
    # ...
    $track_e = $tracker->getProjectTrack($id, $usr_elem, $taski, $start, $end);
```